# Fibre of morphism of schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Hartshorne gives the following preamble to the definition of a *fibre of a morphism of schemes.*

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, and let $y \in Y$ be a
>   point. Let $k(y)$ be the *residue field* of $y$, and let $Spec
>  \hspace{0.5mm} k(y) \to Y$ be the natural morphism as in Exercise 2.7.

Now Exercise 2.7 states that for a scheme $X$ and a field $K$,  to give a morphism $Spec \hspace{0.5mm} K \to X$ it is equivalent to give a point $x \in X$ and an inclusion map $k(x) \to K$.

I am not sure how this exercise applies in this case since our original morphism of schemes $f: X \to Y$ does not have domain an affine scheme.

How is the conclusion of the exercise used?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. You're taking $K = k(y)$. There is an inclusion (equality!) $k(y) \subseteq K$, so the exercise applies to give a morphism $\operatorname{Spec} K \to Y$. This has nothing to do with $f$ yet.

Comment: Ok I see.  I think the word natural is what is throwing me off.

Comment: I think it's "natural" in the sense you choose $Y$ and $y \in Y$ and then this is the only map you can write down. Maybe "canonical" is better. Part of the exercise is probably to prove this.